# Restore-DfsrPreservedFiles on a remote machine

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs-r

I'm trying to restore preexisting files on a DFS share on Server2012r2. No matter what I do, I get this response. This occurs even if I use -RestoreToPath or if I try to run it with the local admin account.

```
PS E:\> Restore-DfsrPreservedFiles -Path "E:\share\DfsrPrivate\PreExistingManifest.xml" -RestoreToOrigin -Force

Restore-DfsrPreservedFiles : Access to path E:\share\DfsrPrivate\PreExisting\username\Data aplikací\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar was denied.
```

The issue seems to be the fact, that the administrator doesn't have the permissions to access some `AppData` stuff. However the DFS service moved it to `PreservedFiles` without an issue, so there has got to be some way of doing this.

I need for `Restore-DfsrPreservedFiles` to work in a `sudo rsync -a` kind of way.

Or at least make it move anything it can access while ignoring errors.

Answer (score 0):

After finding out the original files were in `SHARE\DfsrPrivate\PreExisting\` and only the direct contents had malformed names in a "nice" way, I decided to just move it in file explorer and rename the folders with a regex in powershell. Seems to have worked.